Why the access to /proc/[pid]/ns needs to generate symlinks?
The directories of the form /proc/[pid]/ns get populated each time they are accessed. That is, each time they are accessed the kernel produces a symlink to somewhere in the namespace filesystem (not directly accessible from userspace) and it eventually returns the information that it got from there. If I understand correctly the kernel provides no caching for this operation, which is good because this ensures that even if a task changes some of its namespaces a read to /proc/[pid]/ns will give a correct information.
Given the previous, why is the symlink created? It amounts to allocating a symlink inode and some more stuff in the /proc filesystem which will then be re-allocated or maybe just modified in a subsequent read, but not really used to return any information to userspace, and the latter is the real goal of /proc. Wouldn't it be enough for the read methods of /proc to just go look into the namespace filesystem?

Things in filesystems of type proc (which generally covers /proc) are dynamic.  They are not "created" and do not actually exist.  Since they don't exist, they can't be cached by the kernel.
These are not created on access.   Things in there are not what they appear.
Consider this to be a kernel API.  When you access things in /proc the kernel provides a view on its internal data structures that just looks like files, but they are not real and are not allocated and do not take any memory beyond the return data from the system call that is viewing them.
The symlink file object is used in /proc to represent a relationship, and the symlink target doesn't necessarily exist or point to a valid path and the file metadata (including file size and even inode number) is not guaranteed to be useful.
Very likely when you look at /proc/$$/ns the kernel is returning data from the namespace data structures directly.  In some cases the inode may be created in memory and cached, but this might be only to preserve the inode number.  The file contents are dynamically generated on the fly every time.

Thanks for your reply. Are you sure about your last line? For example, I think this is allocating an inode for a symlink /proc/[pid]/ns/foo. Also, I think the inode numbers are meaningful, they are just allocated by the allocator in the namespace filesystem, so they will be unrelated to the inode numbes in the root filesystem.

I didn't say the inodes were not meaningful.  I said they were not guaranteed to meaningful. Or unique.  Also, even if proc allocates an inode in memory today and holds it in inode cache, there's nothing preventing a patch next week removing that code and implementing it differently without allocating an inode.

It seems like a big patch and I guess its plausibility is my question

It has happened to other proc subsystems already.

do you know any?

eventfs probably...some interesting discussion about that in Jan 2024.
